# Error: Cannot subscript a value of 'Dictionary with an index of type 'Int64'

Tags: swift, dictionary

```
var dict = Dictionary<Int64, ExternalInfo>()
```

Create an extension for the above dictionary like

```
extension Dictionary where Key: IntegerLiteralConvertible, Value: ExternalInfo {

    func contains(id: Int64) -> Bool {
        return self[id] != nil
        /* return self[3] != nil */ // No issue
    }

    mutating func remove(id: Int64) {
        removeValueForKey(id)
    }
}
```

It throw some compiler level error for both statement. What need to do??

> Cannot subscript a value of 'Dictionary with an index of
>   type 'Int64'

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `SignedIntegerType` instead of `IntegerLiteralConvertible`, this is a better common protocol between different integer type:

```
extension Dictionary where Key: SignedIntegerType, Value: ExternalInfo {

    func contains(id: Int64) -> Bool {
        return self[Key(id)] != nil
    }

    mutating func remove(id: Int64) {
        removeValueForKey(Key(id))
    }
}
```